# Passenger with apache2 server for ruby is not starting

Tags: ruby, apache, webserver, apache2, passenger

**Problem**: I am not able start the ruby application with passenger + apache2

Ruby Version: **ruby 2.1.2p95** (2014-05-08 revision 45877)

Phusion Passenger **5.0.29**

OS: **Debian 8 jessie**

**Apache/2.4.10**

When starting apache with following command then getting error in the logs.

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

tail -f /var/log/fk-portkey/production.log

```
Initializing Phusion Passenger...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1041 14486/7fc3bde5e740 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1553230863
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1042 14486/7fc3bde5e740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:698 ]: Starting Watchdog...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1043 14486/7fc3bde5e740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/lib/ruby-flo/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '3', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.58', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.58', 'web_server_pid' => '14485', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1109 14489/7fd1250f7740 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1553230863
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1111 14489/7fd1250f7740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:643 ]: Starting PassengerHelperAgent...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1137 14489/7fd1250f7740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14485/generation-0/request
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1265 14495/7ff2ad310780 agents/Base.cpp:1591 ]: Random seed: 1553230863
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1306 14495/7ff2ad310780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:333 ]: Starting PassengerLoggingAgent...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1319 14495/7ff2ad310780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.14485/generation-0/logging
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1325 14486/7fc3bde5e740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1350 14485/7f8602b75780 apache2/Hooks.cpp:1583 ]: Shutting down Phusion Passenger...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1362 14489/7fd1250f7740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:599 ]: Received command to exit gracefully. Waiting until 5 seconds after all clients have disconnected...
[ 2019-03-22 10:31:03.1368 14486/7fc3bde5e740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:741 ]: Web server exited gracefully; gracefully shutting down all agents...
```

[image]

When I start the application with the following command then getting error in the logs.

> sudo /etc/init.d/fk-portkey start

tail -f /var/log/fk-portkey/production.log

Error: https://pastebin.com/gDJ9W8jt

Content of [/tmp/passenger-error-Xjl3B1.html](https://pastebin.com/368BHG90)

When reloading apache getting following logs

> /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
>
> tail -f /var/log/fk-portkey/production.log

```
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4026 11018/7fa77d79a700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4027 11027/7f22a3ff5700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4027 11018/7fa782ca1780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:901 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4027 11027/7f22a37f4700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4028 11027/7f22a37f4700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4031 11018/7fa75dffb700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4032 11018/7fa75dffb700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4034 11018/7fa75effd700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.5] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4035 11018/7fa75effd700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.5] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4035 11018/7fa75f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4036 11018/7fa75f7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4037 11027/7f22a9286780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4041 11018/7fa77d79a700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4042 11018/7fa75e7fc700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.6] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4043 11018/7fa75e7fc700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.6] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4043 11018/7fa75ffff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4043 11018/7fa75ffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4042 11018/7fa77d79a700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4053 11018/7fa77cf18700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4054 11018/7fa77cf18700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4402 11054/7f9245b52780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4574 11058/7f82fd844780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4578 11058/7f82fd844780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4632 11058/7f82fd844780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 11058
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4768 11067/7f04580e0780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4781 11067/7f04580e0780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 11067
[ 2019-03-25 14:57:07.4904 11018/7fa782ca1780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
App 11170 stdout:
```

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. What is the content of mentioned `/tmp/passenger-error-Xjl3B1.html`? 3. Have you read and tried suggested https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems?

Comment: I have updated the question with the content of the html file. I have already checked the troubleshoot page but couldn't figure out the issue. I will give one more try and update the findings in the question. Please do not close the question. I am struggling with this issue from more than 4 days.

Comment: Is it intended to run it with `Ruby 2.1.0`? What your `Gemfile` specifies for ruby version?

Comment: Previously, I was using Passenger on 1.9.3 where it was working fine now I have upgraded to 2.1.0. I have read in some places that the passenger should be working fine on ruby 2.1.0.

Comment: Well, `Passenger` should (did you upgrade `Passenger` btw?) but the rest of your application is not promised to survive the major version upgrade.

Comment: My application is a microservice developed on Padrino framework with minimum gems. To make it work on 2.1.0 I needed to upgrade only couple of Gems but Passenger was not needed to upgrade so it is using same version as before.

Comment: Then it’s indeed strange. Does it start up successfully in `dev` environment? `test`? `prod` locally?

Comment: Yes, application is working properly on test and dev but not working on production.

Comment: Is there any error when you do a `bin/rails c production`?

Comment: @siegy22, This is a Padrino microframework.

Comment: Ah, sorry something got mixed up in my brain with a previous question I was reading.
Can you start a puma/webrick or a plain irb console in production environment of the padrino framework?

Comment: @siegy22, I am able to open Padrino console as development environment on production machine.

Comment: Yes, but can you open your console in production environment? Because passenger (if not otherwise configured) will boot the app in production mode.